# Jquery plugin stops placeholder to appear

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so I have a jquery tag plugin which works perfectly, but then I thought ho!, it would be cool to add a "placeholder"to my text box.  I did so... and nothing appeared apart from the jquery plugin... My place holder should be "hello type here"... I guess it doesn't work, because of the plugin, which is between "script" tags...  I would be very thankful if someone could help me:)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="tag-it.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <link href="jquery.tagit.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <form name="myForm" action="searchlevel.html" method="post">
            <p id="text">Sport:</p>
            <input type="text" name="query" id="box" placeholder="hello type here! ">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="but">
        </form>
    </body>
    <script>
        //this is jquery tag plugin...  

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#box").tagit();

        });

        // I guess I have to add something here to display the "placeholder", please help.
    </script>
</html>
```

Aloha to you mate!

Comment: The placeholder attribute is supported in Internet Explorer 10, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and Safari. Which browser are you using?

Comment: From the doc : https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/blob/master/README.markdown#placeholdertext-string . It has an option for placeholder

Comment: chrome  Sherin Mathew

Answer (score 1):

why are you using tagit javascript and css for placeholder. delete that scripts and use it simple it will work , but remember its only create problem when you will it in IE <9

look at here may help you

`JSFiddle`[Test here](http://jsfiddle.net/n47wr7et/2/)